# GLEW unknown type name

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks, glew

I'm trying to skip the "link step" of glew by adding the sourcefile to my project, to make the code more flexible (target 32 and 64 bit with little modifications). I already achieved 32 bit compilation with Code::Blocks and mingw 32 bit. Now I'm stuck trying to compile the code in 64 bit! (mingw 64 bit with code::blocks). I can't get rid of this error:

`in glew.c:
error: unknown type name for 'hPFNGLQUERYOBJECTPARAMETERUIAMDPROC'
error: conflicting types for '__glewQueryObjectParameteruiAMD'`

Both in line 636 of glew.c. The same code compiled successfully with no modifications at all with the 32 bit compiler (tough no same pc). I'm using the header glew.h (and the other ones) that came with the sourcefile.

Comment: Do you clean the whole project, before switching the architecture? Is it possible, that some files are built for x32, others for x64.

Comment: Yes, I re-built all .o files to make sure they were for the right architecture. Problem solved, was that extra h, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `h` at the begining of `hPFNGLQUERYOBJECTPARAMETERUIAMDPROC`, it has to be `PFNGLQUERYOBJECTPARAMETERUIAMDPROC` without the leading `h`.

Comment: I surely changed it accidentally while moving all those files, thank you so much!